# How to remove an item that appears multiple times in a list by Python?

Tags: python

I am a python beginner and I am wondering how to remove an item that appears multiple times in a list by Python. Here is my list:

```
["0101013132","0101410142","0101430144"]
```

The first thing I want to do is to replace all "01" by "1", the second thing is to replace"31","32" by "3" respectively and replace "41","42","43","44" by "4" respectively.

I have no idea how to do so. Thank you!

Sorry for confusion. What I want is to turn my list into this one:
["11133","11414","11414"]

Comment: <s>Just use `set`.</s> Didn't read carefully. My bad.

Comment: @PhilipTzou How does that answer the question?

Comment: Are there patterns like `12`, `13` in the string? what are you going to replace them with?

Comment: This question really needs clarification. "01" is not an element of the list. It is a substring of some of the elements of the list. I say forget the list, worry about one string. Use the `replace` methods of strings

Comment: `"31","32"` does not occur anywhere in your list.  Did you mean you want to _separately_ replace `31` with `3`, and then replace `32` with `3`?

Comment: The title doesn't seem to correspond to the question..
Let's make an example and tell us how it should work:
"0101410142" => "1141142" => "11414"
Then should we go on with => "1144" => "114" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_list = ["0101013132","0101410142","0101430144"]
normalized_list = []
for item in my_list:
    normalized_list.append(item.replace('01', '1').replace('31', '3').replace('32', '3')) # and so one...)


print(normalized_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L = ["0101013132","0101410142","0101430144"]
answer = [s[::2].replace('0', '1') for s in L]

In [7]: answer
Out[7]: ['11133', '11414', '11414']
```

Comment: If you delete the `replace` it returns the same thing. You just take every other digit, ignoring the first one. I don't think that's what he meant (although I can't really tell...)

Comment: @EllaShar: thank you for the bug report. It's fixed now

Answer (score 0):

```
l =  ["0101013132","0101410142","0101430144"] 
[ ''.join( map( lambda x : str(x)[0]  ,map( int, map(''.join, zip( *( [iter(s)]*2) ) ) ) ) )  for s in l ]
```

Comment: You divide each number to groups of 2 digits each, then you replace '01' by '1' using `int` and '32' by '3' (etc) by taking the first digit. Is that what he wanted? Interesting...